# website scraping soccer analytics with bs5

Tags: python, json, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have adopted this code from a medium post, currently it works for the first `id` but is not looping through the ranges:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd


understat_ids = range(16376, 16755+1)
match_data = []


for id in understat_ids:
    base_urls = f'https://understat.com/match/{id}'
#Use requests to get the webpage and BeautifulSoup to parse the page
    res = requests.get(base_urls)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')
#get only the shotsData
    strings = scripts[1].string

# strip unnecessary symbols and get only JSON data
    ind_start = strings.index("('")+2
    ind_end = strings.index("')")
    json_data = strings[ind_start:ind_end]
    json_data = json_data.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')

#convert string to json format
    data = json.loads(json_data)

x = []
y = []
xG = []
result = []
team = []
minute = []
data_away = data['a']
data_home = data['h']
date = []
player = []
situation = []
shotType = []
matchId = []

for index in range(len(data_home)):
    for key in data_home[index]:
        if key == 'X':
            x.append(data_home[index][key])
        if key == 'Y':
            y.append(data_home[index][key])
        if key == 'h_team':
            team.append(data_home[index][key])
        if key == 'xG':
            xG.append(data_home[index][key])
        if key == 'minute':
            minute.append(data_home[index][key])
        if key == 'result':
            result.append(data_home[index][key])
        if key == 'situation':
            situation.append(data_home[index][key])
        if key == 'date':
            date.append(data_home[index][key])
        if key == 'player':
            player.append(data_home[index][key])
        if key == 'shotType':
            shotType.append(data_home[index][key])
        if key == 'match_id':
            matchId.append(data_home[index][key])


for index in range(len(data_away)):
    for key in data_away[index]:
        if key == 'X':
            x.append(data_away[index][key])
        if key == 'Y':
            y.append(data_away[index][key])
        if key == 'a_team':
            team.append(data_away[index][key])
        if key == 'xG':
            xG.append(data_away[index][key])
        if key == 'minute':
            minute.append(data_away[index][key])
        if key == 'result':
            result.append(data_away[index][key])
        if key == 'situation':
            situation.append(data_away[index][key])
        if key == 'date':
            date.append(data_away[index][key])
        if key == 'player':
           player.append(data_away[index][key])
        if key == 'shotType':
            shotType.append(data_away[index][key])
        if key == 'match_id':
            matchId.append(data_away[index][key])




col_names = ['x','y','xG','minute','result','situation','date','player','shotType','team','match_id']
df = pd.DataFrame([x,y,xG,minute,result,situation,date,player,shotType,team,matchId],index=col_names)
df = df.T
```

The above code works for one match the first `ID` specified in `range`, how can I edit this code to loop through each match id appending them on to a `pandas` `dataframe`?

It seems like the code needs a small edit to be able to do this.

Comment: When you define `data` in your first `for` loop, you don't do anything with it, you just go on to the next iteration of the loop. Therefore, when you get down to defining `data_away` and `data_home`, you're just using the last value assigned to `data` in the last iteration of the loop. You need to rearrange your code and indent properly to ensure that either everything is processed within the loop, or your data is added to a collection like a list and iteratively processed later. Also, in your last `for` loop, use a dict instead of all those individual lists. DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned @MattDMo you have to check and adjust your indentation properly to ensure that either everything is processed within the loop.

Removing all these `if-statements` and `lists`, that are not necessary would improve readability of your code - Use a single line with `list comprehension` to create a `list` of `dicts` that you convert to a `dataframe`:

```
...
data = json.loads(json_data)
match_data.extend([d for k in data.keys() for d in data[k]])
    
pd.DataFrame(match_data)
```

##### Example

For demonstration I decreased the number of iterations, feel free to adjust it to your needs

```
import requests,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

understat_ids = range(16376, 16400+1)
match_data = []

for id in understat_ids:
    base_urls = f'https://understat.com/match/{id}'
#Use requests to get the webpage and BeautifulSoup to parse the page
    res = requests.get(base_urls)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')
#get only the shotsData
    strings = scripts[1].string

# strip unnecessary symbols and get only JSON data
    ind_start = strings.index("('")+2
    ind_end = strings.index("')")
    json_data = strings[ind_start:ind_end]
    json_data = json_data.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')

#convert string to json format
    data = json.loads(json_data)
#iterate JSON and extend match_data with a list of dicts
    match_data.extend([d for k in data.keys() for d in data[k]])
    
pd.DataFrame(match_data)
```

##### Output

|  | id | minute | result | X | Y | xG | player | h_a | player_id | situation | season | shotType | match_id | h_team | a_team | h_goals | a_goals | date | player_assisted | lastAction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 425564 | 10 | MissedShots | 0.913 | 0.539 | 0.053464 | Frank Onyeka | h | 9681 | OpenPlay | 2021 | Head | 16376 | Brentford | Arsenal | 2 | 0 | 2021-08-13 19:00:00 |  | Aerial |
| 1 | 425565 | 11 | ShotOnPost | 0.908 | 0.315 | 0.118297 | Bryan Mbeumo | h | 6552 | OpenPlay | 2021 | RightFoot | 16376 | Brentford | Arsenal | 2 | 0 | 2021-08-13 19:00:00 | Ivan Toney | Throughball |
| 2 | 425567 | 21 | Goal | 0.874 | 0.698 | 0.0521447 | Sergi Canos | h | 1078 | OpenPlay | 2021 | RightFoot | 16376 | Brentford | Arsenal | 2 | 0 | 2021-08-13 19:00:00 | Ethan Pinnock | BallRecovery |
| 3 | 425568 | 27 | MissedShots | 0.812 | 0.478 | 0.0657062 | Sergi Canos | h | 1078 | OpenPlay | 2021 | RightFoot | 16376 | Brentford | Arsenal | 2 | 0 | 2021-08-13 19:00:00 | Frank Onyeka | Pass |
| 4 | 425569 | 29 | MissedShots | 0.892 | 0.357 | 0.0806906 | Bryan Mbeumo | h | 6552 | OpenPlay | 2021 | RightFoot | 16376 | Brentford | Arsenal | 2 | 0 | 2021-08-13 19:00:00 | Kristoffer Ajer | Chipped |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 650 | 428704 | 77 | SavedShot | 0.868 | 0.596 | 0.122391 | Abdoulaye Doucouré | a | 1726 | OpenPlay | 2021 | RightFoot | 16400 | Brighton | Everton | 0 | 2 | 2021-08-28 14:00:00 | Demarai Gray | Pass |
| 651 | 428708 | 83 | BlockedShot | 0.913 | 0.688 | 0.0734056 | Alex Iwobi | a | 500 | OpenPlay | 2021 | RightFoot | 16400 | Brighton | Everton | 0 | 2 | 2021-08-28 14:00:00 | Richarlison | Pass |
| 652 | 428709 | 83 | SavedShot | 0.778 | 0.753 | 0.0136589 | André Gomes | a | 2383 | FromCorner | 2021 | RightFoot | 16400 | Brighton | Everton | 0 | 2 | 2021-08-28 14:00:00 |  | None |
| 653 | 428711 | 90 | BlockedShot | 0.939 | 0.723 | 0.0615859 | André Gomes | a | 2383 | OpenPlay | 2021 | LeftFoot | 16400 | Brighton | Everton | 0 | 2 | 2021-08-28 14:00:00 | Alex Iwobi | Pass |
| 654 | 428712 | 93 | BlockedShot | 0.704 | 0.703 | 0.015702 | Lucas Digne | a | 1823 | OpenPlay | 2021 | LeftFoot | 16400 | Brighton | Everton | 0 | 2 | 2021-08-28 14:00:00 | Allan | Pass |